# image wrong place

Tags: graphics, texstudio, ubuntu

Latex shows the following code in this order:

> Fig1
>
> Conclusion
>
> Fig2

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=140mm]{fig1.png}
\caption{fig 1}
\label{fig:f1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=140mm]{fig2.png}
\caption{fig 2}
\label{fig:f2}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}
conclusion goes here
```

Even changing `h` to `H` is not much better:

> Conclusion
>
> Fig1
>
> Fig2

Comment: You can try `ht!`. If you want to use `H` then you need `\usepackage{float}`

Comment: See the first answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163644/figure-appearing-in-completely-wrong-place

Comment: @R.Schumacher What is the conclusion? Even `H` does not work.

Comment: Don't tell LaTeX to move the image if you don't want LaTeX to move the image. It is the essence of floats to float.

Comment: using `h` prevents the float going at top or bottom of pages and prevents it going on a page with just floats so makes it almost impossible to place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The problem is that the images could not be fit into one page. by resizing them, they became fine:

```
\includegraphics[width=140mm]{fig2.png}
```

to

```
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{fig2.png}
```

Comment: You could also use `\linewidth` for `width`

Answer (score 3):

Try using the float package.  I put a minimum example below.  I have now used the H option along with specifying a height for the pictures which is too large for two pics and conclusion to fit on one page.  The figures now come first and the conclusion follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height= 80mm,width=140mm]{fig1.png}
\caption{fig 1}
\label{fig:f1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height= 80mm,width=140mm]{fig2.png}
\caption{fig 2}
\label{fig:f2}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}
conclusion goes here
\end{document}
```

Note:  I used the demo option of the graphicx package as I did not have your images and I guessed a picture height.

Comment: Then it put both images after conclusion. The problem is that size of images are big for one page. Any way to force latex starting conclusion only when both figs are shown before it?

Comment: @ar2015 Edited the code to force the order.